# Structuring events following events?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, structure, addeventlistener

I'm attempting to build a canvas drawing app that will zoom into a line drawing (on mousedown) and then draw on that zoomed in square (also using mousedown)

I think there is a problem with the structure of my code - not sure how to arrange the functions so that the first part - select a square and zoom - is followed by the second part - drawing app.  I've attempted to stick the whole thing in the zoom app so the zoom function is called it then stops the event listener and starts the drawing app, but this hasn't worked.

I hope this is clear - can anyone see where I'm going wrong?
Thanks
Nick

Here's the code:

```
function doFirst() {
var x=document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas=x.getContext('2d');
pic = new Image ();
pic.src = "kingtut.jpg";
pic.addEventListener ("load", function()
{canvas.drawImage(pic, 0, 0,1200, 600);},false);
var radius = 10;
dragging = false;
}

function square (e) {
var xPos = Math.floor(e.clientX/200)*200;
var yPos = Math.floor(e.clientY/100)*100;
canvas.drawImage(pic, 0, 0,1200, 600);
canvas.strokeRect (xPos, yPos, 200, 100);
}


function zoom (e) {
var scale = 6;
var xPos = Math.floor(e.clientX/100)*100;
var yPos = Math.floor(e.clientY/100)*100;
canvas.translate(-xPos*scale, -yPos*scale);
canvas.scale(scale,scale);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){e.stopPropagation();zoom}, true);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
var putPoint=function (e) {
if (dragging){
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
canvas.fill();
canvas.beginPath();
canvas.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
}
}
var engage = function (e) {
dragging = true;
putPoint(e);
}

var disengage = function (e) {
dragging = false;
canvas.beginPath();
}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", zoom, false);
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", square, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bubbling event model, that all web browsers folowing, is quite simple:

There is a lot of events that provided by browser. You can lister them.
In additional you can lister other events, that provided by other control or by your code.

Other code relation binding is provided by you code pattern, in your case it is OOP.

So, in JavaScript case:

If you want to listen event you should bind function to the event:

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", zoom, false);
```

(You bind to event "mousedown" function "zoom")

If you want to stop listen event you should unbind function from event:

```
window.removeEventListener ("mousedown", zoom, false);
```

(You unbind from event "mousedown" function "zoom")

But!! if you write:

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", zoom, false);
window.addEventListener("mousedown", engage, false);
```

You bind function "zoom" to the event "mousedown" 2 times! So it called twice.

So, according to your code, you should add

> removeEventListener

Before you want override listener, sample:

```
window.removeEventListener("mousedown", zoom, false);
window.addEventListener("mousedown", engage, false);
```

Good luck! :)